# Is it acceptable to post questions and immediately answer it?

Tags: discussion

I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27281383/how-to-change-password-in-rdp-session) and noticed it had been almost immediately answered by the poster, within less than a minute of it being posted. I understand it's acceptable to ask questions and answer them yourself if you solve the question yourself at a later time, but the response time on his answer leads me to believe he is just attempting to get some quick rep.

A quick browse of his profile shows that every question he has asked has been answered by himself, with 3 of them being within a minute of posting.

Is it acceptable to post a question, knowing the answer at the time of writing it, and then posting the answer immediately?

Comment: Yes.  There's even a button to post them both together on the ask question page itself - see the "Answer your own question" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it acceptable to post questions and immediately answer it

Yes, it's welcomed as long as it's not a duplicate and is of good value.
See here:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

However, that Q&A pair doesn't look like it will be very frequently useful to many users at all.  Which arguably makes it useless/pointless.

The way to resolve that is if it can be fairly downvoted, and/or flagged for some reason.
At least some comments might be useful to let them know why this is not particularly useful.

Comment: Also, they need to be on-topic, which [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296901/how-can-i-assign-static-ip-address-in-microsoft-routing-and-remote-access-servic) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27281383/how-to-change-password-in-two-level-rdp-session) fail at.  (I'd vote to close, but I'm out of votes for the day)